# How long can a teacher form daily groups so that no two students meet more than once?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

**Loose motivation:** Suppose that a teacher wants to form new groups in class every day in such a way that maximizes the number of days before any two students are in a group together on two separate days.

**Formal setup:** Let S be the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, and let $d$ divide $n$. Let a *$d$-partition* of $S$ be a set of $\frac{n}{d}$ disjoint subsets of $S$ each of size $d$. For any $i\in S$ and any $d$-partition $P$, let $P(i)$ denote the unique element of $P$ containing $i$. If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are both $d$-partitions of $S$, call the pair $(P_1,P_2)$ *fresh* if for all $i\in S$ we have $P_1(i)\cap P_2(i)=\{i\}$.

In other words, if we think of the elements of $S$ as students in a class, and $P_1$ and $P_2$ are the $d$-partitions describing the groups for days 1 and 2, then $(P_1,P_2)$ is fresh if no two students were together on both days.

**Question:** What is the largest $m$ such that $\{P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_m\}$ is a set of pairwise fresh $d$-partitions of $S$? Or in other words, how many days can the teacher continue to make groups so that so that no two students are in a group together more than once?

I'm hopeful the answer is constructive (ie. there is some sort of algorithm for producing the $P_i$). I'm also interested in generalizing to the case where $d$ does not divide $n$, and we want $n-d\lfloor\frac{n}{d}\rfloor$ groups of size $d+1$ and $\lfloor\frac{n}{d}\rfloor(d+1)-n$ groups of size $d$.

I'm sure something like this has been studied before, and my notions of $d$-partition and fresh are likely called something else in the literature. I'd be happy with a solution or a reference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A good deal is known about the existence of the limiting block designs which are *resolvable* (can be partitioned into "parallel classes", each of which constitutes a partition of $\{1,..,n\}$ into subsets of size $d$) and in which every pair appears exactly once in some block (subset of size $d$).

Comment: The more general case, in which pairs appear *at most* once (rather than exactly once) are called by many authors *resolvable packing designs* with fixed block size $d$ (to match your notation; $k$ is more commonly used [to designate the fixed block size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design)).  For the specific case of block size $4$ a relatively recent reference is [GE, Lam, Ling and Shen, 2007](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10623-003-6739-6), *Resolvable Maximum Packings with Quadruples* (abstract only, paper itself is behind a paywall).

Comment: I'll put together a broader answer, but have a look at these classroom notes on [resolvable BIBDs](http://math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m6406/resolvable.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

[Kirkman's schoolgirl problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem).

Comment: I think the [Social Golfer Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem.html) would serve as a more general topic of reference.  In any case we should advise the OP that no explicit solution for all $n$ divisible by $d$ is known.